# Invalid declartion of sqlite_step function in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I've a problem while retrieving sqlite table records.
I've included

```
while (sqlite_step(&statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
.....
.....
}
```

This statement is showing a warning '**implicit declaration of function sqlite_step is invalid in C99**' and later on throwing an error '**Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_sqlite_step",....**' while compilation. Please help me out.

Comment: remove '&' from while (sqlite_step(&statement) == SQLITE_ROW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
```

Comment: I've included sqlite_step instead of sqlite3_step.. Working fine now.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This line causes issue:

```
while (sqlite_step(&statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
```

Change it to

```
while (sqlite_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
```